# How to change lock screen?

Tags: unity, 15.10, kde, login-screen

I installed KDE in ubuntu 15.10, but the login screen is the one that comes with Unity. Is there any way to use KDE login screen instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can change what display manager you are using with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

This will pull up a selection menu with all DMs currently installed. KDE/Kubuntu uses `sddm`.

Comment: ```┌─[julian][ubuntu][~]
└─▪ sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
[sudo] password for julian: 
┌─[julian][ubuntu][~]
└─▪```

Nothing happened :(

Comment: Then the full KDE package was not installed, and `kdm` was not installed as a result. `sudo apt-get install kdm`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to ubuntu, I'm getting this error: `Package kdm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  kde-wallpapers

E: Package 'kdm' has no installation candidate`

Comment: Try that package: `kde-wallpapers`.

Comment: The KDM has been replaced with the SDDM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Desktop_Display_Manager .  Ubuntu packages: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sddm&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: Ah, thank you for that update! I'ts been a while since I've used KDE, I guess :P.